# Android Studio - Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android-studio

I just installed android studio. after I run the application on android studio, an error appears.

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

.> Multiple task action failures occurred:

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\6860334808920ca12b2cd0121824eebd\transformed\jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\235f02541b7028202c8adb4d579147bb\transformed\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\fd628b3502225c9494311d76a802f459\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\37bfbfccd4c6da91c9f2f0341a36f0de\transformed\jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5bcef036683d3be56754a92e0512461a\transformed\jetified-emoji2-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\056a8fbc280e47ced48cf8bf3b636210\transformed\core-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\74bea9fc6e761f50ff5f7907cd190e20\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

.> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\transforms-3\525e4913fd690e9549498febc17fcc14\transformed\lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the patch according to your current react-native version:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

In my case I updated react-native to patch version 0.64.4 in `package.json` file.
Run `npm install`.
Run `cd android && ./gradlew clean` to clean Android artifacts.
Re-run your app.

I hope this help.